# How VS.net framework executes unit test case written in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

How framework comes to know about the unit test class exists in your source code , what are the sequence of operatiosn it performs

Comment: kindly answer this question rather underestimating my questions

Comment: it uses reflection and looks for attributes in files. e.g. [TestMethod] or [Fact]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are struggling to find a unit test in the test explorer.

```
        [TestClass]
    public class YourTestClass
    {
      [TestMethod]
      public void YourTest()
      {
        int TestInt = 1;
        Assert.IsTrue(TestInt == 1);
      }
     }
```

Here is an example of the most basic unit test I can think of. 
Have your unit test inside a class file within your unit test project and make sure to save all files and Re-Build your solution.

Once you have saved all files and Re-Built the solution please check within the test explorer for your test again.

Comment: my question was how test execution engine works in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad so no short answer can cover all the technical details.

A rough statement is that VS defines standard API for unit test framework authors to adapt to, so that when VS asks for their unit test providers they respond with what are the detected test cases, and how the cases should be executed.

You can find the xUnit.net Visual Studio addin so as to gain more insights.

https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit

Other IDEs use other approaches, like Visual Studio for Mac/Xamarin Studio and MonoDevelop,

https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit